# Why do my images appear on the next page?

Tags: graphics

I write this code but my images appear on the next page.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/imageGray.png}
    \caption{Imaginea originala}
  \end{minipage}
  \hfill
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{images/imageBlur.png}
    \caption{Imaginea blurata}
  \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Are the contents of the `figure` environment maybe taller than the space that's available at the bottom of the page? If so, that would explain why LaTeX is forced to place the figures at the top of the subsequent page.

Comment: If you have not loaded the float package, then [H] is undefined and the figure is floating like it should.  If [H] is defined, then you should get a large gap at the bottom of the page.  (Friends don't let friends use H.)

Comment: you have not shown any code that could allow anyone to help.Assuming you have defined `[H]` (you should get an error message if not) then you will get a page break if it does not fit at that point. So what you show may be expected behaviour, but it is impossible to tell as you have not shown whether the bears would fit on the previous page or not.